# eval arithmetic expression as a string vs calling function

Tags: performance, perl, eval

I was going to advice some fellow Perl developers against eval-ing formulas as a string each time the formula is calculated, and instead eval - once - functions for each formula. Thus, instead of calling eval thousands of times, a function is called. I.e:

Instead of:

```
sub calc_formulas_naive
{
    my %formulas;
    $formulas{formula_a} = '$ref->{metric_a} + $ref->{metric_b} * $ref->{metric_c} - 100 * $ref->{metric_c} / 1000 + 33.33 * $ref->{metric_d}';
    $formulas{formula_b} = '$ref->{metric_a} * $ref->{metric_c} - 33';
    $formulas{formula_c} = '$ref->{metric_a} * $ref->{metric_c} - 33 + 0.265 * ($ref->{metric_d} / $ref->{metric_c}) - $ref->{metric_a} + $ref->{metric_e} * ($ref->{metric_d} + 1)';

    my $ref = shift @_;
    my $form_a_val = eval $formulas{formula_a};
    my $form_b_val = eval $formulas{formula_b};
    my $form_c_val = eval $formulas{formula_c};
}
```

Use:

```
my %formulas_adv;
sub prep_formulas_adv # called only once prior to parsing!
{
    my $sub = 'sub { my $ref = shift @_; my $result = $ref->{metric_a} + $ref->{metric_b} * $ref->{metric_c} - 100 * $ref->{metric_c} / 1000 + 33.33 * $ref->{metric_d}; return $result; }';
    $formulas_adv{formula_a} = eval $sub;
    $sub = 'sub { my $ref = shift @_; my $result = $ref->{metric_a} * $ref->{metric_c} - 33; return $result; }';
    $formulas_adv{formula_b} = eval $sub;
    $sub = 'sub { my $ref = shift @_; my $result = $ref->{metric_a} * $ref->{metric_c} - 33 + 0.265 * ($ref->{metric_d} / $ref->{metric_c}) - $ref->{metric_a} + $ref->{metric_e} * ($ref->{metric_d} + 1); return $result; }';
    $formulas_adv{formula_c} = eval $sub;
}

sub calc_formulas_advanced
{
    my $ref = shift @_;
    my $form_a_val = $formulas_adv{formula_a}($ref);
    my $form_b_val = $formulas_adv{formula_b}($ref);
    my $form_c_val = $formulas_adv{formula_c}($ref);
}
```

Now the question itself. I was totally sure that 2nd approach gives noticeable advantage when processing big amounts of data. I haven't had access to my old projects, but I also was quite sure I saw the 2nd approach working faster than the 1st. After all, Perl doesn't have to compile anything on-the-run in this case.

But before giving the advice, I wrote a small artificial example with 5K text files populated with rand generated metrics, ran both implementations, and... I don't observe any advantage of using unnamed functions over strings evaluation.
What's the matter? Was I hallucinating all the time, when I thought that eval is less effective than a function?

Comment: Sure it's less efficient. Is the difference enough to matter? In your (small) test case, apparently not. If you want to measure the difference, make your test cases larger. If the test cases are representative of actual use, then you've answered your question.

Comment: Ah... Yes, will try on my larger case. When I was using it in real project, there were thousands of files with thousands of individual metrics, and formulas were giant, one formula sometimes could take a page of text.

Comment: Benchmarking is hard.  Perl's `Benchmark` module is great, but easy to misuse in ways that render the results meaningless.  I recommend basing your tests on Perl's Benchmark module, but used with care.  Please post the actual code you used to benchmark the sample code, and the benchmark results. It is also useful to employ Test::More with tests written to prove that the different versions are equivalent.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using `eval` at all. In these examples, you could simply have used an anonymous sub: `$formulas_adv{formula_a} = sub { my $ref = shift @_; ... };`

Comment: Because formulas themselves were specified in files which had to be provided in a runtime.

Comment: Are you simply asking us to benchmark for you???

Comment: No. I was concerned not seeing immediate effect on small test case, that's why I posted. But after I started to increase formulas length, I started to see advantage of evaluating subs once. So consider this closed. Thanks!